# If $g_m\geq 0$ then $\int \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} g_m d\mu =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \int g_m d\mu$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

### If $g_m\geq 0$ then $\int \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} g_m d\mu =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \int g_m d\mu$.

I have proved the part that if $\int \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} g_m d\mu$ is finite then the equality holds.

But I could not find a way to prove that--- if $\int \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} g_m d\mu$ is infinite but none of $\int g_m d\mu$ are infinite, then also the equality holds.

Comment: Have you tried the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: yeah! Problem in $\infty$ part.

Comment: A good thing about MCT is that it does not care whether the integral converges or not. So if you managed to resolve the convergent case using MCT, exactly the same argument will apply unconditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\int g_m$ is finite. Then
$\int h_M\le A$ where $h_M=\sum_{m=0}^M g_m$. The sequence $(h_M)$
is pointwise increasing. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$H=\lim_{M\to\infty} $ is integrable and $\int H=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int h_M$.
This is the equality you seek.

In all other cases both sides are $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty\int g_m d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=0}^n\int g_m d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\sum_{m=0}^n g_m d\mu$$

Then,using MCT theorem, we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\sum_{m=0}^n g_m d\mu=\int\sum_{m=0}^\infty g_m d\mu$$